# How do I change linked stylesheets?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Inbetween the `<head></head>` of my WordPress theme is a broken link to a google font stylesheet. How do I either remove the link or change it? In the `index.php` it's just showing `wp_head()`.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='tesseract-fonts-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%2BSans%3A400%2C‌​300%2C300italic%2C40‌​0italic%2C600%2C600i‌​talic%2C700%2C700ita‌​lic%2C800%2C800itali‌​c%26subset%3Dlatin%2‌​Cgreek%2Cgreek-ext%2‌​Cvietnamese%2Ccyrill‌​ic-ext%2Ccyrillic%2C‌​latin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

This is the URL:

[http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%2BSans%3A400%2C‌​300%2C300italic%2C40‌​0italic%2C600%2C600i‌​talic%2C700%2C700ita‌​lic%2C800%2C800itali‌​c%26subset%3Dlatin%2‌​Cgreek%2Cgreek-ext%2‌​Cvietnamese%2Ccyrill‌​ic-ext%2Ccyrillic%2C‌​latin-ext](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%2BSans%3A400%2C%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B300%2C300italic%2C40%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B0italic%2C600%2C600i%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Btalic%2C700%2C700ita%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blic%2C800%2C800itali%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bc%26subset%3Dlatin%2%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BCgreek%2Cgreek-ext%2%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8BCvietnamese%2Ccyrill%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bic-ext%2Ccyrillic%2C%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Blatin-ext)

Comment: Could you specify the url of the _link to the google font stylesheet_ that you consider as broken?

Comment: As soon as I get home, I'll paste it.

Comment: <link rel='stylesheet' id='tesseract-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%2BSans%3A400%2C300%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%26subset%3Dlatin%2Cgreek%2Cgreek-ext%2Cvietnamese%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Ccyrillic%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet will be loaded using `wp_register_style` probably in the functions.php

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will look as soon as I get home.

Comment: Thoroughly searched through functions.php, did not find wp_register_style.

Comment: I was wrong, it was there wp_enqueue_style( 'tesseract-fonts', tesseract_fonts_url(), array(), '1.0.0' );

Answer (score 0):

Deregister/Dequeue styles is best practice

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style

But you can use this filter too, to filter out styles with any condition:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```